# Multiple Key Event Bindings in Tkinter - "Control + E" "Command (apple) + E" etc

Tags: events, binding, command, key, tkinter

Mac OS X 10.6.6 - Tkinter

I want to bind multiple-key events, and while I have found an effbot article and the Tk man pages, I've been unable to make this work correctly. I'm new here.

I've had mixed success. I've been able to get Shift + letter key, but not Control or Command (Apple key). What I really want to do is Command + letter and Control + letter key so it would theoretically work in Windows and OS X.

I want it to work at window-level, so I'm using root. Perhaps there is a better way. Below is what I've tried:

```
root.bind('<Shift-E>', self.pressedCmdE)   # Works
root.bind('e', self.pressedCmdE)           # Works
root.bind('<Command-E>', self.pressedCmdE) # Does Not Work
#root.bind('<Mod1-E>', self.pressedCmdE)   #   # Do Mod1, M1, and
#root.bind('<M1-E>', self.pressedCmdE)     #   # Command mean the same thing?
```

---

Strangely, when I press alt/option + (E, N, or others) it creates an error. Is it interacting with PythonLauncher?

```
2011-06-16 16:19:22.618 Python[1546:d07] An uncaught exception was raised
2011-06-16 16:19:22.621 Python[1546:d07] *** -[NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds
2011-06-16 16:19:22.622 Python[1546:d07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85b397b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff848b90f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85b395d7 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 103
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85b39564 +[NSException raise:format:] + 148
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff866eb5e1 -[NSCFString characterAtIndex:] + 97
    5   Tk                                  0x0000000100759bcf Tk_SetCaretPos + 663
    6   Tk                                  0x000000010075fd94 Tk_MacOSXSetupTkNotifier + 699
    7   Tcl                                 0x000000010061d2ae Tcl_DoOneEvent + 297
    8   _tkinter.so                         0x00000001001d9be9 init_tkinter + 1132
    9   Python                              0x0000000100089187 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15317
    10  Python                              0x000000010008acce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
    11  Python                              0x000000010008935e PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15788
    12  Python                              0x000000010008acce PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1803
    13  Python                              0x000000010008ad61 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
    14  Python                              0x00000001000a265a Py_CompileString + 78
    15  Python                              0x00000001000a2723 PyRun_FileExFlags + 150
    16  Python                              0x00000001000a423d PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 704
    17  Python                              0x00000001000b0286 Py_Main + 2718
    18  Python                              0x0000000100000e6c start + 52
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Abort trap
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Tk. I get the same error with tcl/tk on the mac as well as with python/tkinter. You can bind `<Command-e>` to a widget (I tried with a text widget) but binding it to the root window or to `"all"` seems to cause the error you get.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the experience to know whether it's an error or my error...usually mine.

Answer (score 24):

With Tkinter, "Control-R" means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> whereas "Control-r" means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>. So make sure you're not mixing up uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: This is a very important note. But it seems to me, you are right only particularly. 

All depends on the letter case. `"<Control-R>"` means Ctrl-Shift-R only when the Caps Lock is **disabled**, otherwise it is equal to Ctrl-R.

And "<Control-r>" binding means Ctrl-R only when Caps Lock is disabled, and Ctrl-Shift-R when Caps Lock is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Something like this:

```
# Status of control, shift and control+shift keys in Python
import tkinter as tk

ctrl = False
shift = False
ctrl_shift = False

def key(event):
    global ctrl, shift, ctrl_shift
    #print(event.keycode, event.keysym, event.state)
    if ctrl_shift:
        print('<Ctrl>+<Shift>+{}'.format(event.keysym))
    elif ctrl:
        print('<Ctrl>+{}'.format(event.keysym))
    elif shift:
        print('<Shift>+{}'.format(event.keysym))
    ctrl = False
    shift = False
    ctrl_shift = False

def control_key(state, event=None):
    ''' Controll button is pressed or released '''
    global ctrl
    ctrl = state

def shift_key(state, event=None):
    ''' Controll button is pressed or released '''
    global shift
    shift = state
    control_shift(state)

def control_shift(state):
    ''' <Ctrl>+<Shift> buttons are pressed or released '''
    global ctrl, ctrl_shift
    if ctrl == True and state == True:
        ctrl_shift = True
    else:
        ctrl_shift = False

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('256x256+0+0')

root.event_add('<<ControlOn>>',  '<KeyPress-Control_L>',   '<KeyPress-Control_R>')
root.event_add('<<ControlOff>>', '<KeyRelease-Control_L>', '<KeyRelease-Control_R>')
root.event_add('<<ShiftOn>>',    '<KeyPress-Shift_L>',     '<KeyPress-Shift_R>')
root.event_add('<<ShiftOff>>',   '<KeyRelease-Shift_L>',   '<KeyRelease-Shift_R>')

root.bind('<<ControlOn>>', lambda e: control_key(True))
root.bind('<<ControlOff>>', lambda e: control_key(False))
root.bind('<<ShiftOn>>', lambda e: shift_key(True))
root.bind('<<ShiftOff>>', lambda e: shift_key(False))
root.bind('<Key>', key)

root.mainloop()
```

**Option 2**

However, in the end, I decided to process keystrokes manually. You can se the example in [this file](https://github.com/foobar167/junkyard/blob/master/manual_image_annotation1/polygon/gui_main.py). First, I set keycodes and shortcuts in two dictionaries `self.keycode` and `self.__shortcuts`:

```
# List of shortcuts in the following format: [name, keycode, function]
self.keycode = {}  # init key codes
if os.name == 'nt':  # Windows OS
    self.keycode = {
        'o': 79,
        'w': 87,
        'r': 82,
        'q': 81,
        'h': 72,
        's': 83,
        'a': 65,
    }
else:  # Linux OS
    self.keycode = {
        'o': 32,
        'w': 25,
        'r': 27,
        'q': 24,
        'h': 43,
        's': 39,
        'a': 38,
     }
self.__shortcuts = [['Ctrl+O', self.keycode['o'], self.__open_image],   # 0 open image
                    ['Ctrl+W', self.keycode['w'], self.__close_image],  # 1 close image
                    ['Ctrl+R', self.keycode['r'], self.__roll],         # 2 rolling window
                    ['Ctrl+Q', self.keycode['q'], self.__toggle_poly],  # 3 toggle between roi/hole drawing
                    ['Ctrl+H', self.keycode['h'], self.__open_poly],    # 4 open polygons for the image
                    ['Ctrl+S', self.keycode['s'], self.__save_poly],    # 5 save polygons of the image
                    ['Ctrl+A', self.keycode['a'], self.__show_rect]]    # 6 show rolling window rectangle
```

Then added `self.__keystroke` function to monitor `<Ctrl>` keystroke events. This function checks if `<Ctrl>` key is pressed or not:

```
def __keystroke(self, event):
    """ Language independent handle events from the keyboard """
    #print(event.keycode, event.keysym, event.state)  # uncomment it for debug purposes
    if event.state - self.__previous_state == 4:  # check if <Control> key is pressed
        for shortcut in self.__shortcuts:
            if event.keycode == shortcut[1]:
                shortcut[2]()
    else:  # remember previous state of the event
        self.__previous_state = event.state
```

Finally, bind the `self.__keystroke` function to the master GUI window. Note that this function is bonded **in the idle mode**, because multiple keystrokes slow down the program on weak computers:

```
# Handle keystrokes in the idle mode, because program slows down on a weak computers,
# when too many key stroke events in the same time.
self.master.bind('<Key>', lambda event: self.master.after_idle(self.__keystroke, event))
```

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced to cover the `Alt` and `Meta` keys, aka `Option` and `Command` on macOS.

```
# Original <https://StackOverflow.com/questions/6378556/
#           multiple-key-event-bindings-in-tkinter-control-e-command-apple-e-etc>

# Status of alt (ak option), control, meta (aka command)
# and shift keys in Python tkinter

# Note, tested only on macOS 10.13.6 with Python 3.7.4 and Tk 8.6.9

import tkinter as tk
import sys

_macOS = sys.platform == 'darwin'
_Alt   = 'Option' if _macOS else 'Alt'
_Ctrl  = 'Control'
_Meta  = 'Command' if _macOS else 'Meta'
_Shift = 'Shift'

alt = ctrl = meta = shift = ''


def up_down(mod, down):
    print('<%s> %s' % (mod, 'down' if down else 'up'))
    return down


def key(event):
    '''Other key pressed or released'''
    # print(event.keycode, event.keysym, event.down)
    global alt, ctrl, meta, shift
    t = [m for m in (alt, ctrl, shift, meta, str(event.keysym)) if m]
    print('+'.join(t))


def alt_key(down, *unused):
    '''Alt (aka Option on macOS) key is pressed or released'''
    global alt
    alt = up_down(_Alt, down)


def control_key(down, *unused):
    '''Control key is pressed or released'''
    global ctrl
    ctrl = up_down(_Ctrl, down)


def meta_key(down, *unused):
    '''Meta (aka Command on macOS) key is pressed or released'''
    global meta
    meta = up_down(_Meta, down)


def shift_key(down, *unused):
    '''Shift button is pressed or released'''
    global shift
    shift = up_down(_Shift, down)


def modifier(root, mod, handler, down):
    '''Add events and handlers for key press and release'''
    root.event_add('<<%sOn>>' % (mod,), ' <KeyPress-%s_L>' % (mod,), '<KeyPress-%s_R>' % (mod,))
    root.bind(     '<<%sOn>>' % (mod,), lambda _: handler('<%s>' % (down,)))

    root.event_add('<<%sOff>>' % (mod,), '<KeyRelease-%s_L>' % (mod,), '<KeyRelease-%s_R>' % (mod,))
    root.bind(     '<<%sOff>>' % (mod,), lambda _: handler(''))


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('256x64+0+0')

modifier(root, 'Alt',     alt_key,     _Alt)
modifier(root, 'Control', control_key, _Ctrl)
modifier(root, 'Meta',    meta_key,    _Meta)
modifier(root, 'Shift',   shift_key,   _Shift)

root.bind('<Key>', key)

root.mainloop()
```