# How to get Tkinter Mac-friendly menu shortcuts (cmd+key)

Tags: python, tkinter, shortcut

I am considering shortcuts for Tkinter menu labels (commands).
On Macs the combination with cmd ⌘ is common.

So far I have found only `self.bind_all("<Control-q>", self.quit)`. How to implement cmd ⌘ shortcuts?

Then again, thinking about - once the app is finished - translating it to an executable file for Windows and a Mac application might cause difficulties when using cmd ⌘?
What is the best way of dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would need to specify one of the **Meta and M** Modifiers listed at [Tk Built-in Commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/bind.htm#M6) -- perhaps `Mod1` instead of `Control`. You might also find this list of [keysyms recognized by Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) useful.

Although I've never actually every tried to do it -- if all else fails -- you might be able to determine what you need to know by writing your own event handler function `def handlerName(event):`,  bind it to `'<Any-KeyPress>'` events, and then, in the function `print` the values of the attributes of the event argument being passed it when it's called -- such as `event.keycode`, `event.keysym`, `event.keysym_num`, etc -- thereby allowing you to see what to use for detecting ⌘-key modified keystrokes on your Mac.

Lastly, Python is open-source, so you can always try reading that.

Update: From the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379851/355230) it sounds like the `Command-` would work.