# How do I get the Mac "command" symbol in a Tkinter menu

Tags: python, macos, unicode, tkinter, accelerator

I've written a Python program for a friend's business, and am using Tkinter for the interface.  Up until now, all features have been added in the main program window, but I'm now adding a print feature, have created a simple "File" menu, and want to add a "Print" entry to that menu, including displaying the relevant keyboard shortcut.

On my Mac, I want the shortcut to be Command-P.  I found the Mac "command" symbol's Unicode value, and have tried various ways to create an accelerator string that simply concatenates that symbol and the letter "P", but nothing works.  I get either the symbol or the letter to display in the menu next to "Print", but never both.

Here is the full line of code that adds the menu item, with the latest attempt at building the string (I believe I found this `unicode.join` option elsewhere in Stack Overflow):

```
sub_menu.add_command(label="Print", command=self.print_, accelerator=unicode.join(u"\u2318", u"P"))
// Only the "P" displays
```

Here are some of the other options that I've tried (lines truncated for clarity).  With each of these options, only the "command" symbol appears:

```
accelerator=u"\u2318\u0050"
accelerator=u"\u2318" + "P"
accelerator=u"\u2318" + u"P"
accelerator=u"\u2318P"
accelerator=u"".join([u"\u2318", u"P"])
```

Up until now I haven't had a need to learn much about Unicode strings, so perhaps there's something I'm doing wrong in that regard.  However, all of the attempts that I've made have come as a result of various searches, both here and elsewhere, and so far nothing has worked.  Any insight into how to make this work would be most welcome!

Python 2.7.3, Mac OS X 10.8.3

Comment: '<Command-Button-P>' from my brief googling .. but that may not work ...

Comment: Does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379877/how-to-get-tkinter-mac-friendly-menu-shortcuts-cmdkey/16471555#16471555) of mine help?

Comment: @Joran and @martineau: Both of your comments refer to the handling of the keystroke event itself, but that's not my problem.  I'm trying to figure out how to use the `accelerator` argument of the menu's `add_command` method to display "⌘P" as the keyboard shortcut for a menu item.  The solutions that I listed above either give me "⌘" or "P", but not both characters together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further searching online, I finally found [a page](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html) that has the solution.  I was surprised (and a touch annoyed) that this solution was different than the one outlined in the PDF documentation for Tkinter 8.4 that I've been referencing thus far (the one published by New Mexico Tech).  I found links to Tkinter 8.5 documentation, but they also list the incorrect process.

Anyway, it's a lot simpler than I thought, and is similar to the syntax used for key binding, but slightly different.  Instead of directly including the command symbol in the accelerator string, Tkinter takes the literal word "Command" (or the abbreviated "Cmd"), and internally converts it to the displayable character "⌘" in the menu.  So my resulting line is:

```
sub_menu.add_command(label="Print", command=self.print_, accelerator="Command-P")
```

...and what I get in my full menu item is:

```
Print ⌘P
```

As the page linked above shows, similar shortcut words exist for other modifier keys, and on Mac OS X, these are all automatically translated into their graphical equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

It was actually really easy, all I did was use `string formatting` to concatenate `text="%s%s" % (u"\u2318","P")`

Here is a sample `Tkinter App`, the display is small but it shows what you need.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.label = tk.Label(text="%s%s" % (u"\u2318","P"))
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
⌘P
```

Comment: While that works for labels, it doesn't work for menus, which is my original problem.  I finally found the solution after further web searching, and will post my answer shortly.