# Binding keys in Mac OS X - Tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit, key-bindings

I have a code that works perfect in a Ubuntu system. This is just a minimal code based on it:

```
import tkinter as Tk
import tkFileDialog 
import ttk

class AppGUI(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):  
        self.ctrl = False
        self.parent = parent
        self.centerWindow()
        self.initGUI()
        self.plot()

    def initGUI(self):
        # Notebooks
        self.notebook  = ttk.Notebook(self.parent)
        self.frame_one = Tk.Frame(self.notebook)   # first page
        self.frame_two = Tk.Frame(self.notebook)   # second page
        self.notebook.add(self.frame_one, text='Notebook 1')
        self.notebook.add(self.frame_two, text='Notebook 2')
        self.notebook.pack(side = Tk.TOP, fill="both", expand=True)

        # Realization frame
        self.out_frame = Tk.Frame(self.parent, bd=1, relief=Tk.SUNKEN)
        self.out_frame.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill="both", expand=True)

        # Key events
        self.key()

    def centerWindow(self):
        w = 800
        h = 800

        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2
        self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))


    def key(self):
        # Key events
        def press(event):
            self.ctrl = True
        def release(event):
            self.ctrl = False

        self.parent.bind('<Control_L>', press)
        self.parent.bind('<KeyRelease-Control_L>', release)

    def plot1(self):
        f = plt.figure(figsize=(1, 1), dpi=300)
        c_plot1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.frame_one)
        c_plot1.show()
        c_plot1.pack(side=Tk.LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)

        def onClickPlot1(event):
            if event.inaxes is not None:
                if self.ctrl:
                    print "Control key pressed"
                    # Do my stuff

        c_plot1.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClickPlot1)

    def plot2(self):
        # Same stuff for plot 2

    def plot(self):
        self.plot1()
        self.plot2()


def main():
    root = Tk.Tk()
    app = AppGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run thin in a Ubuntu machine, I can see that whatever `Control` key I press (left or right control) is correctly binded, as I see the print and the expected visual result. Running the same code in a Mac, on the other hand, I cannot see the print output and, of course, the expected result doesn't happens.

I followed [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) document to perform the binding. I'm not trying to use the Mac `Command` key, just the regular left `Control`.

Are there different biding codes for different systems? This doesn't make sense, but I can't find the problem.

Comment: bind `<Key>` and `print()` all you get in `event` when you press `Control` and you will see what you get - maybe it uses different code (ie. `Meta_L`).

Comment: see: [how-to-get-tkinter-mac-friendly-menu-shortcuts-cmdkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379877/how-to-get-tkinter-mac-friendly-menu-shortcuts-cmdkey)

Answer (score 2):

There are three different types of keys:

1. Normal Keys; for example : s ,a ,1 ,9 and ...
2. Punctuation Key; for example 'Left' , 'Up', 'bracketright'(']') , 
   ! , % and ...
3. Special keys; for example:

   - **'Meta_L' (command in mac)**
   - **'Alt_L' (alt in mac)**
   - **'Control_L' (ctrl in mac)**
   - **'super_L' (fn in mac)**
   - **'Shift_L (shift in mac)**
   - **'Caps_Lock'**
   - **And also combination keys like fn+F2 are punctuation keys.**

```py
# bind and show a key press event with Tkinter
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
prompt = '      Press any key      '
label1 = Label(root, text=prompt, width=len(prompt), bg='yellow')
label1.pack()
def key(event):
    if event.char == event.keysym:
        msg = 'Normal Key %r' % event.char
    elif len(event.char) == 1:
        msg = 'Punctuation Key %r (%r)' % (event.keysym, event.char)
    else:
        msg = 'Special Key %r' % event.keysym
    label1.config(text=msg)
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
root.mainloop()
```

The above code says it all ;)

Comment: Very helpful. But I'd change one bullet-point: Alt_L (Option key in mac)