# How do you create hotkeys like Ctrl+s with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a text editor and i need the Ctrl+s, Ctrl+shift+s and Ctrl+o hotkeys to finish its final update

I tried using pynput but that blocked the tkinter mainloop

Can you help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple-key-event-bindings-in-tkinter-control-e-command-apple-e-etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
Master = Tk()
def putcommandhere(event):
           print ('hello')

Master.bind('<key>', putcommandhere)
```

Comment: You probably don't want to bind to `<Key>` since that will fire for every single keypress. A better example would be to show how to bind specifically to control-s.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, as mentioned by β.εηοιτ.βε, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26397090)

Comment: this does work but it fires on launch even if i dont press the key

Answer (score 1):

There are not hotkey bindings in TKinter for things like `ctrl+s` but you can add any hotkeys to any window with two bindings and a little state management.

```
from tkinter import *
Master = Tk()
ctrl_pressed = False
def master_key_pressed(event):
  # ctrl key pressed
  if event.keycode == 17:
    ctrl_pressed = True
  # 'ctrl+s' pressed
  elif event.keycode == 83 and ctrl_pressed:
    pass
def master_key_released(event):
  # ctrl key released
  if event.keycode == 17:
    ctrl_pressed = False
Master.bind('<Key>', master_key_pressed)
Master.bind('<KeyReleased>', master_key_released)
```

There is a [partially complete list](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/key-names.html) of the key names.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and run! It's working! Python 3.10

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tk.Tk()

def save_current_file(event=False):
    messagebox.showinfo(message='File saved! (fake)')

# hotkey to save current file
window.bind('<Control-s>', save_current_file)

window.mainloop()
```